# Помогите с ошибкой json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json

Вот код:

```
def func():
    while True:
        parseresult = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/trade-request-give-p2p?key=' + marketkey).json()
        time.sleep(2)
        if parseresult['success'] == True:
            resultfrommarket = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/trade-request-give-p2p?key=' + marketkey).json()
            resultfromsteam = requests.get("http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key=" + api + "&get_sent_offers=1&active_only=1").json()
            xx = resultfromsteam.get('response')
            time.sleep(2)
            if xx != {}:
                trade_id = resultfromsteam["response"]["trade_offers_sent"][0]["tradeofferid"]
                time.sleep(2)
            else:
                func()
            if resultfrommarket['success'] == True:
                if resultfrommarket["offer"]["tradeoffermessage"] == resultfromsteam["response"]["trade_offers_sent"][0]["message"]:
                    time.sleep(2)
                else:
                    func()
                if resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent'][0]['trade_offer_state'] == 9:
                    time.sleep(2)
                    client._confirm_transaction(trade_id)
                    print(time.asctime() + "  подтвердили")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    func()
                else:
                    func()
func()
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 50, in <module>
    func()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 36, in func
    func()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 47, in func
    func()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 49, in func
    func()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 49, in func
    func()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 49, in func
    func()
  [Previous line repeated 15 more times]
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tradeconfirm.py", line 25, in func
    parseresult = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/trade-request-give-p2p?key=' + marketkey).json()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Как это можно решить?

Comment: Что должен делать этот странный конструкт?

Comment: делает запрос,делает другой,сравнивает в обоих данные,если они верны то подтверждается обмен

Comment: Вы уверены, что Вам возвращается `Json`? Посмотрите, что возвращает сервер (3 строка).

Comment: json.Работает от силы часа два,дальше дает трейсбек

Comment: Может try exept попробовать? ошибка всегда одинаковая

Comment: @artemso72 Может, через некоторое время сервер возвращает ошибку? Или стоит какое-то ограничение? Попробуйте логировать запросы и посмотреть, какой именно привёл к ошибке и какие данные были в ответе.

Comment: Ну так может сделать Try exept?я не смогу сделать логирование

Comment: @artemso72 В консоль печатайте то, что Вам возвращает сервер. После этого уже парсите `Json`. Когда возникнет ошибка, посмотрите последний напечатанный ответ. "Костыльное логирование"